# How to get last item in white space separated words in cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

For example I have 500+ rows of data that is formatted as example:
Hamilton Washington 30 OR 12345

The issue is the last item in the cell is a zip code and I need to copy it into another cell.
The number of items in each cell is not the same so split text leaves it in different columns.

I essentially want the "12345" or last item in the cell since for all of them it will be the zip code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function below & adjust it to your own setup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A," ",REPT(" ",10)),10)))
```

### Sample Result:

[image]

### Reference:

[**Extract the Last Word In Excel & Google Sheets**](https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/extract-last-word/)

[**TRIM**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)

[**RIGHT**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087)

[**SUBTITUTE**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)

[**REPT**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your original string data is in A2:A. You could place the following formula in B2 (assuming B2:B is empty first):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\s([\S]+)$")))`

This means "If a cell in `A2:A` is blank, leave the corresponding cell in `B2:B` blank; otherwise, return the last group of non-spaces that follows a space and ends with the end of the string."